# Microsoft SQL Studio - Creating table with 2 new columns and other being copied

Tags: sql-server, copy

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Studio 2012. I want to create table that contains 2 columns that I'm going to insert later, but I also want this table to contain some columns from another table. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT ET.column_name1, ET.column_name2, -- column from existing table
'' new_column_name                       -- column where you will insert later
INTO new_table                           -- new table
FROM existing_table_name ET              -- existing table
```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: With this answer you win the internet for today. The question made no sense but your answer seems to have nailed it. Nice mind reading.

Comment: Well when I use this I get an error saying that: Invalid object name 'poistnik'.  `SELECT ET.id, ET.typ_poistky, ET.vyska_platby, ET.datum_uzatvorenia, '' datum_platnosti INTO poistky FROM poistnik ET; ` this is my code

Comment: Invalid object name 'poistnik' might have occured because your table named 'poistnik' doesn't exist in your selected database.

Comment: oh, my. I'm blind. Somehow after a while of not working with tables, program stopped using my database, that was the deal. Don't know why. Anyway it helped, thanks, but now I got another problem. When I try to insert data into `new_column` it says **String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.**

Comment: Ok, new column was varchar(1) that's why it didn't work, I fixed it now. Thanks for help again.